# How can I extract an archive with the archive's name as a directory to a path?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, unzip

I found this command.
`for f in *.zip; do unzip -d "${f%*.zip}" "$f"; done`

I want something similar to this, but I want to extract my zip files from my `~/Downloads` folder to `~/Documents`.

So.

```
- Downloads
    - zip1.zip
    - zip2.zip
    - zip3.zip

- Documents
    - zip1/data.txt
    - zip2/data.txt
    - zip3/data.txt
```

Please, help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just prefix the path your provide in the -d flag with the Documents directory:

```sh
for f in *.zip; do unzip -d ~/Documents/"${f%*.zip}" "$f"; done
```

Note that the script still needs to be executed inside your downloads directory.

Comment: Yes, thank you, but how would I get the folder where to extract it from? I don't just want to `cd` to the folder and use this command. I want to do this from the home folder.

Comment: Do `for f in ~/Downloads; ...` and you will be able to do it from any directory.